# ignore certain columns in where clause sql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

I have created a test DB to try and figure this out. I created a sales table which has an amount,sale_made (when the sale was made) and item description in the table.I'm trying to do it by only using one table only, I want to get the sum of all items sold overall, the number of items sold overall and half the total amount of days selling items. here is my query

```
select sum(amount) as 'total amount for all items sold'
,count(amount) as 'Total items sold',
 count(sale_made)as 'half total days' from sales where sale_made BETWEEN "2018-07-02" and "2018-07-05" ;
```

the query is working but the where clause is affecting the overall sum(amount) and the volume of items sold. is there a way I can keep the where clause in an not affect those first two columns?

i have tried self-joining the table and using table alias names but that doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(amount) as `total amount for all items sold`,
       count(amount) as `Total items sold`,
       sum(sale_made between '2018-07-02' and '2018-07-05') as `half total days`
from sales;
```

Notes:

- Single quotes are for string and date constants (ANSI-standard).  That is why I change the double quotes to single quotes.
- MySQL uses backticks to escape names.  I don't like column aliases that need to be quoted, but you are using them, so I chose backticks (double quotes would also work).
- MySQL has a convenient shorthand of treating booleans as integers in a numeric context, with "1" for true and "0" for false.  Hence the use of `sum()` for the third column.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick and easy to understand answer, solved my issue with ease